# Image preloader with in Underscore template

Tags: jquery, json, underscore.js

I am working on a thumbnail gallery which is getting populates with JSON data using underscore template. Just Want to put an image preloader for thumbnails images using new Image() object.

Please correct me where i went wrong because below code is not working for me. Also suggest if my approach is not correct.

```
<!-- Template for Thumbnail GRID -->
<script type="text/template" id="grid-listing-template">
    <% if(!_.isUndefined(data)) {
        var images = [];
        _.each(data, function(result, i) {
    %>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 item">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="<%=result.href%>" title="<%=result.title%>">
                    <div class="loader" style="display:block; height: 100px;"></div>
                    <img class="img-responsive thumb" src="" alt="<%=result._alt%>" style="display: none;">
                    <%
                        images[i] = new Image();
                        images[i].src = result._src;
                        images[i].onload = function() {
                            $('.thumb').attr('src',result._src);
                            $('.thumbnail .loader').remove();
                        };
                    %>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <p><%=result.caption%></p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <%
        });
    %>
    <% } %>
```

Comment: What specifically does "not working" mean in this context? What are you expecting to happen and what actually does happen? And don't you think that `$('.thumb')` and `$('.thumbnail .loader')` are a little broad? Those selectors will match all the thumbs and loaders that are in the DOM.

Comment: i want a loader image to appear till thumbnail image loads. As soon as image loads then loader image will disappear.

Comment: I think it will be difficult to make this work solely inside the template. The problem is that the template won't know when its HTML version has been added to the DOM so how do you know how to find your `<img>`s? You need a node so that you can `$x.find(...)` or they need to be in the DOM so that `$(x)` will work. You could use `id` attributes (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/vE4Bs/) but getting the timing right can be tricky. I think you'll have a better time using data attributes for the real `src` in the template and then doing the `new Image` stuff after the HTML has been added to the page.